# asp.net export to Access

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to export my generic list by doing the following.

I'd like to use the Access object model in .net and create an Access database in a memory stream populate it with my list and send it for download all in one click of a button.

Is that possible? Would this work under heavy load? Better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article should help get you started: [How to create an Access database at runtime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388971/how-i-create-access-database-at-runtime-in-c).

It describes how to create an MS Access database on-the-fly to which you will add your data.

Though the above method seems relatively complicated, I might suggest that you offer something a little more flexible such as a comma separated file (.csv).  A user may then choose to import it to excel, access, or any other application that supports the import of a .csv (there are many).