# Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I created a MS Access database at runtime and tried to create a table.
Below code is showing the error "Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement" while creating a table at runtime.

```
cmmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE tblContacts( [SectionID] AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,[ScetionName] Text(50), [CatID] Number(Integer), [Rate] Number(Double), [Prefix] Text(5), [Suffix] Text(5), [NextNumber] Number(Integer), [Inactive] Yes, [ModUserID] Number(Integer),[ModDate] Date)";
cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: [By learning the basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx)

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388971/how-i-create-access-database-at-runtime-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Access db engine will balk at field type declarations such as `Number(Integer)`.  Assuming you will execute the statement from an OleDb connection, use this one ...

```
cmmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE tblContacts( [SectionID] COUNTER PRIMARY KEY,[ScetionName] Text(50), [CatID] Long, [Rate] Double, [Prefix] Text(5), [Suffix] Text(5), [NextNumber] Number(Integer), [Inactive] YesNo, [ModUserID] Long,[ModDate] DateTime)";
```

You can find a table which includes valid Access DDL field type declarations here: [Field type reference - names and values for DDL, DAO, and ADOX](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html)

Comment: Thank you @HansUp. It worked well. Please help me in doing relationships. The CatID should be from the Category table? How to relate it CatID field to tblCategory?

Comment: Use the `REFERENCES` key word.  See [here](http://allenbrowne.com/func-DDL.html#CreateTableDDL) for an example --- look at the example under *"Create the Booking table"*.  Post a new question if you run into trouble.