# Regarding creation of database in MS ACCESS using C# code dynamically

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

Is there any way i can create a MS ACCESS Database dynamically by writing code in C# ?  I need this for my college project.

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388971/how-i-create-access-database-at-runtime-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [ADOX and Visual C# .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317881).